# react production build, assets not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am experiencing annoying problem, when i run my react app in development environment it all works ok, but when i try to build to production, all the links are wrong.

assume this tree:

- main_directory

  - public/

    - svg/

      - some_img.svg
  - src/

    - components/

      - some_component.jsx
    - App.js
    - index.js

Now in `some_component.jsx` i am referencing svg file in this way:

```
src="/public/svg/some_img.svg"
```

however after building to production this path is untouched and therefore cannot access file anymore, as there i would need it to be changed to this:

```
src="svg/some_img.svg"
```

i was playing in the webpack config file, i thought that maybe by setting:

```
publicPath: "/"
```

to:

```
publicPath: "/public/"
```

would resolve the problem but the only thing it did was error during application start:

```
CANNOT GET/
```

my webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./public/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: "main.[hash:8].js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader?presets[]=react"
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader", "postcss-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: "svg-sprite-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [htmlPlugin],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [{ from: /^\/$/, to: "/index.html" }]
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
  }
};
```

How does one resolve this problem, so for both dev and production paths are unified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solve for the question, config required for to specify path:

```
module: {
    ...
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query:{
                outputPath: './img/',
                name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
            }
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about importing the svg and then referencing the imported variable:

```
import someImg from "../../public/svg/some_img.svg"

src={someImg}
```

Comment: this doesnt help anyhow, i have additional modules for svg processing and wont work like that, what i need is way to configure webpack for it.

Comment: As far as I know, this method is the generally accepted method for loading images with webpack.

Comment: this (if at all) only would solve importing of svg files in jsx components, and how i am suppose to handle path to images in css? in development paths look different then for production

Comment: Path in css, you would handle the same. Relative paths to where your css is. sass/css loader fixes that for you and translates the path to the correct one. On your jsx, you should NOT import like that.

Comment: use `import mysvg from '../../path/to/wherever/it/is'` on jsx, `url('../../mysvg')` on css.

Comment: @Mevia hopefully it helps. you asked about jsx originally, but PlayMa has been kind enough to provide a css solution as well.

Comment: i brought up jsx as example, its not what i asked for, i asked for how to setup unified path for dev and production using webpack.

Comment: this topic actually solves my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590538/loading-css-url-files-in-a-specific-folder-with-webpack